# How to define copy constructor and deallocate pointer

Tags: class, pointers, constructor, destructor, allocation

I ran cppcheck, and it turns out that I need to have a copy constructor for this class. I do not know how to define a copy constructor in this case. Any suggestions?

```
class Simulator{


    private:

        int xMax;// = 40; //SIZE;
        int yMax;// = 40; //xMax; // 40
        //int TTMxSize = 4000;
        //const int CarMxSize = 500;
        //const int WaitListSize = 4000;
        double base_price;// = 0.85 / 4;
        double saev_vott;// = 0.35;
        char* mode_output;// = "modeChoiceStats_supply_charge.csv";    

        vector<Car>** CarMx;//[xMax][yMax];
        vector <Station>** ChStMx;//[xMax][yMax];
        vector<int> **cellChargeCount;
            vector<int> **cellChargeTime;
        int timeTripCounts [288];           

        // Functions for program

    public:
        Simulator();
        Simulator(int fleet_size, int seed, char* inputFile);
        ~Simulator();
        bool loadParameters(char* input);
        void printParameters();
        void placeInitCars();
    bool lookForCar (int x, int y, int r, int dist, int& cn);
    void assignCar (int x, int y, int c, Trip* trp);
void setBusinessTripProbability();

        void runSimulation();
};

Simulator::~Simulator()
{
    for (int x=0; x<xMax; x++)
    {
        delete [] CarMx[x];
        delete [] ChStMx[x];
        delete [] cellChargeCount[x];
        delete [] cellChargeTime[x];
    }

    for (int x=0; x<numZonesL; x++)
        delete [] zoneSharesL[x];

    for (int x=0; x<numZonesS; x++)
        delete [] zoneSharesS[x];

    delete [] CarMx;
    delete [] ChStMx;
    delete [] cellChargeCount;
    delete [] cellChargeTime;
    delete [] zoneSharesL;
    delete [] zoneSharesS;
}
```

Also, I am getting Resource Leak error in the following function

```
bool Simulator::loadParameters(char* input)
{
   FILE* inputfile;
   inputfile = fopen(input, "r");
   if (inputfile == NULL){
     cout << "Could not open "<<input<<endl;
     return false;
   }
   double inputVal = -1.0;
   char* varStr;
   char* valStr;
   char instring [80];

    while (!feof(inputfile))
    {
        fgets(instring, 80, inputfile);
        comment = instring[0];
        if (comment != '#' && comment != '\n')
        {
            varStr = strtok(instring, "=");
            valStr = strtok(NULL, "\0");

        if (strcmp (varStr, "xMax") == 0) {
        inputVal = strtod(valStr, NULL);
        xMax = 4 * (int) inputVal; 
        } else if (strcmp (varStr, "yMax") == 0) {
        inputVal = strtod(valStr, NULL);
        yMax = 4 * (int) inputVal;
            }
    }
    return true; <<<<<<<<< RESOURCE LEAK: inputfile
}
```

Possible leak in this function: Pointer is not deallocated before being allocated.

```
void Simulator::setBusinessTripProbability()
{

    businessTripProbability = new double[926];
    businessTripProbability  [     0     ] =   0.0000   ;
    businessTripProbability  [     1     ] =   0.0029   ;
    businessTripProbability  [     2     ] =   0.0059   ;........... until [925]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

To create a copy constructor:

```
 Simulator(const Simulator &sim);
```

If you do not plan to use the copy constructor, it's better to delete it:

```
Simulator(const Simulator &) = delete;
```

Resource leak: You need to use fclose(inputfile)

Possible leak: Imagine this code:

```
Simulator simulator;
simulator.setBusinessTripPossibility();
simulator.setBusinessTripPossibility();
```

There is a memory leak here. The businessTripProbability is allocated twice and there is no deallocation. You might have a rule that the public method setBusinessTripPossibility() will never be called twice. But in my humble opinion you should not design classes with such rule. Try to allow arbitrary use of the public class interface.